# What does ld -s mean exactly?

Tags: assembly, linker, nasm, gnu, ld

I tried

```
$ man ld
```

The definition they've provided for the -s option, was a bit above my level of understanding. What exactly does stripping of symbols mean? Please specify any links that I may find useful. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_%28Unix%29

Comment: Thanks for the link!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ld` links a number of object files into a binary. This binary normally contains a symbol table which contains the names, types, sizes, and addresses of all symbols used in your program.

Some times it is desirable to omit this table, for example, when you want to have a smaller binary (in large programs, the symbol table can contain multiple megabytes worth of symbols) or when you don't want to leak information about how the program was implemented—remember, the symbol table contains all function and (static) variable names.

Traditionally, the `strip` utility was used for this purpose. `strip` takes a binary and removes its symbol table as well as other metadata not strictly needed for executing the program such as debug information. However, back then linking and disk IO was slow and people added a `-s` (for strip) option to the linker to not have it emit this information in the first place, speeding up the linking stage by a bit.